# Where is guest ring-3 code run in VM environment?

Tags: windows, vmware, virtualization

According to the white paper that VMWare has published, binary translation techinology is only used in kernel (ring 0 codes), ring 3 code is "directly executed" on cpu hardware.

As I observed, no matter how many processes are run in the guest OS, there is always only 1 process in the host OS. So I assume all the guest ring 3 code are run in the single host process context. (for VMWare, it's vmware-vmx.exe).

So my question here is, how do you execute so many ring 3 code natively in a single process? Considering most of the windows exe file don't contain relocation information, it cannot be executed somewhere else, and binary translation is not used in ring3 code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Let's talk about `VMX`, which is `Intel VT-x`'s design.

`Intel VT-x` introduces two new modes to solve this problem: `VMX root mode` and `VMX non-root mode`, which are for host and guest respectively. Both modes have ring 0~3, which means the host and guest will not share the same ring level.

A hypervisor running in ring 3 of `VMX root mode`, when it decides to transfer the CPU control to a guest, the hypervisor lanuch `VMLAUNCH` instruction, which allows transfer to `VMX non-root mode` from `VMX root mode`. Then guest ring 3 code now is able to automatically executing in `VMX non-root mode`. All of this is supported by `Intel VT-x`. No binary translation or instruction emulation is needed for running guest.

Of course ring 3 of `VMX non-root mode` has less privilege and power. For example, when a guest ring 3 code encounters somthing it cannot handle, such as a physical device access request, CPU will automatically detect this kind of restriction and transfer back to hypervisor in `VMX root-mode`. After hypervisor finish this task, then it will trigger `VMLAUNCH` again to for running guest.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So part of it is implemented by using hardware assist. But I can't help noticing that VMWare can also run without help of hardware. How is it done?

Comment: VMware ESX is utilizing paravirtualization, similar to Xen, but ESXi I believe is also hardware assisted.

Comment: According to VMWare white paper, neither paravirtualization nor binary translation is used in ring 3 code.